# How to store binary file data in structure?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Hi all,

I have a file shown below(Material.dat) which is binary file , I want to read data from the file and put in the structure for that I have used GetRecord() function.

```
HANDLE hFileMac = ::CreateFile(_T("Material.dat"), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL,
  OPEN_EXISTING, FALSE ? FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN : FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

 if (!(hFileMac != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE))
 {
  return;
 }

 GetRecord(hFileMac, RECORD_NUMBER, sizeof(Header), reinterpret_cast<void *>(&Header));
```

My doubt is what to pass as a record number to Get Record() function?

GetRecord(hFileMac, RECORD_NUMBER, sizeof(Header), reinterpret_cast(&Header));

```
int GetRecord(HANDLE hFile, int RecordNumber, int RecordSize, void *RecordPtr)
{
 if (RecordNumber <= 0 || RecordSize <= 0)
  return 1;
 LONG lOffset = (RecordNumber - 1) * RecordSize;

 if (SetFilePointer(hFile, lOffset, NULL, FILE_BEGIN) == 0xFFFFFFFF)
  return 2;

 DWORD dwSize;

 if (::ReadFile(hFile, RecordPtr, RecordSize, &dwSize, NULL) == 0)
  return 3;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to keep track of the number of entries you have already read. Probably each entry in the binary file has the same size (if not then this function won't work, because it assumes the same size of each element), so providing `RecordNumber` allows offset calculation where to look for this certain entry.

Comment: google protobuf could be solution for you.

Comment: Yes, each entry in the binary file has same size. How to keep track of number of entries and how to calculate offset?  Can you please make me understand clearly.

Comment: @RevanthRao As far as I can see your function reads the record at number `RecordNumber` and does all the calculations correctly.
To be on the save side you might consider writing a little test program to check that the code does what you want though. 

@Rogus The offset is calculated and set from the beginning of the file, so why would he have to keep track of the number of records already read?

Comment: @GertWollny Yes,function reads record at number RecordNumber. What should I pass as a record number?

Comment: @GertWollny Because OP stated that he needs to read data and put it in a structure so he has to know which elements he already has read. If he does it in a loop that's kept in the counter so he doesn't. Could've pointed that out, good call :)

Comment: @RevanthRao The question is, what do want to do with the data? Do you just want to load all material records into an array/vector or do you want to get one specific record?

Comment: @GertWollny I need to store all the material data into a vector of structure ( vector<CW_Materials> Header ) and then I have to fill the materials in a ListControl.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this type of interface:

```
class Record {
  //Reads a single record from "from", incrementing the associated 
  // read pointer, and returning eof or bad, depending on whether record
  // state is consistent, and whether eof stream is reached
  std::istream& read(std::istream& from);
  //Writes a single record to "to"
  std::ostream& write(std::ostream& to);
}

struct MaterialStore {
  //Reads all records from "from", in sequence, using Record interface
  std::istream& read(std::istream& from);

  //Writes all records in "to" to, in sequence, using Record interface
  std::ostream& write(std::ostream& to);

  //Perhaps to perform that seeking for a specific record, the
  // Use Record interface for retrieval.
  std::iostream& seekRecord(std::iostream& stream, int index pos);

  const Record& getRecords(); //Returns all the records read
}
```

Whether read/write is binary, depends on the implementation. Reading and writing is always done consecutively. It may be possible to read a specific record, in which case stream pointer manipulation must be done prior to reading the record. I've added the possibility of seeking in a stream for a specific location (be it read or write), the use the Record interface to read/write.

Answer (score 0):

First to answer the question the way you asked it: To read all the data into a vector I would suggest to change the code to assume that the first record has a RecordNumber=0:

```
LONG lOffset = RecordNumber * RecordSize;
```

Then, to read all records into a std::vector you could do something like

```
struct Record {...}; 
typedef Record* RecordPtr; 
...
std::vector<Record> data_records; 
Record current; 

while (GetRecord(hFile, data_records.size(), sizeof(Record), &current) == 0 ) {
    data_records.push_back(current); 
}
```

Now considering that you read all the records sequentially, you can actually forget about the `RecordNumber`and the call to `SetFilePointer`, because the file read position should be updated by the `ReadFile` call.

In any case, for better portability of the code it would  be better to use file IO functions from the C++ standard library instead of the MS Windows specific calls (like  proposed by WernerErasmus, for details see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)).